# Mongo URI with self signed certificate

Tags: mongodb, ssl

Im trying to get Mongo URI connections to work with a self signed cert.

Command line works just fine, so the following connects:

`mongo mongodb://Qlik:Password1@mongobox.test:27017 --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates`

However, per the docs, there is no `sslAllowInvalidCertificates=true` option for URI connections, nor is there any way to feed a cert in (which would be a problem anyway on my stack)

The URI equivalent:

`mongo "mongodb://Qlik:Password1@mongobox.test:27017/?ssl=true&sslAllowInvalidCertificates=true"`

Results in:

```
2019-10-17T07:19:00.490+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server mongobox.test:27017, connection attempt failed: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get local issuer certificate :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
```

How do you get URI connections to work with self signed certs?

Comment: Did you check the section [Configure mongod and mongos for TLS/SSL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/) of their manual?

Instead of using self-signed certificates, you could pick a free certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org)

Comment: I've concluded that that the answer is "No, you can't use self signed certs with a URI"
In my case, I've managed to get the developers who wrote the app to provide me with a trust store but otherwise for whatever reason, command line an URI are not equivalent connection options.

Answer (score 3):

```
mongo --host example.test \
      --ssl \
      --tlsAllowInvalidCertificates \
      --username myUsername
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this option:

```
tlsInsecure=true
```

The URI will be like this:

```
mongodb://Qlik:Password1@mongobox.test:27017/?tls=true&tlsInsecure=true&tlsCertificateKeyFile=PATH_TO_CLIENT_CERT&tlsCAFile=PATH_TO_CA_CERT
```

Comment: Thanks its remove a lots of hedic from Mongo Altas connection.... very useful this one! :)