# Mongo URI issue - SSL peer certificate validation failed: self signed certificate

Tags: mongodb, uri

I'm using mongo 3.4.4 and I can successfully connect/query using mongo client command line parameters, but not when using the Mongo URI.

This works:

```
mongo --host myfullyqualifiedhostname --port 27018 -u myuser -p mypassword --ssl --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/mongodb-prod.pem --authenticationDatabase admin
MongoDB shell version v3.4.4
connecting to: mongodb://myfullyqualifiedhostname:27018/
MongoDB server version: 3.4.4
rs1:PRIMARY>
```

This does not work:

```
mongo "mongodb://myuser:mypassword@myfullyqualifiedhostname:27018/admin?ssl=true&sslCAFile=/etc/ssl/mongodb-prod.pem"
MongoDB shell version v3.4.4
connecting to: mongodb://myuser:mypassword@myfullyqualifiedhostname:27018/admin?ssl=true&sslCAFile=/etc/ssl/mongodb-prod.pem
2019-12-03T18:25:43.392+0000 E NETWORK  [thread1] SSL peer certificate validation failed: self signed certificate
2019-12-03T18:25:43.398+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for SSL peer certificate validation failed: self signed certificate :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Is there anything missing in the URI so I would get the equivalent to the command line options?

I also tried the URI with sslAllowInvalidCertificates=true&sslAllowInvalidHostnames=true but no luck.

This post mentions someone tried and concluded self-signed certificates does not work when using Mongo URI. Anybody got different results?
[Mongo URI with self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58430161/mongo-uri-with-self-signed-certificate)

Thanks,

Bernardo

Comment: Looking at the MongoDB documentation at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/ it refers to TLS settings - which are replacements for SSL so this information is weak at best.  The docs say there is a parameter for tlsCAFile, but it's new to 4.2, and you are using 3.4.4.  Also, it says this option is NOT available for mongo shell.  In some sense this may bring light to your problem - It seems MongoDB never implemented any option in mongo shell URI connection string to specify a CA file, even with the most recent version.